# How create Flask before_request view for specific views?

Tags: python, flask, before-filter

I'm building a system using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) which contains both a website and an api for an app. I've got a before_request defined for the webviews as follows:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
    # And I do some more stuff here..
```

I've got my views in a folder based structure like this:

```
views (folder)
---------------
  - __init__.py
  - apiviews.py
  - webviews.py
```

Because I'm using a token based login system for the api I now want to define a different before_request for all the apiviews. Is there a way that I can do this? Maybe I need to define a decorator or something? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use a `before_request` hook for specific views, not in the same app.

Your options are to:

- Use a separate `Blueprint` for your API and website; you *can* register a `before_request` per blueprint and it'll be applied to the views for that blueprint only.
- Use per-view decorators rather than `before_request`.
- filter on the request path in the `before_request` handler; `if request.path.startswith(...)` style testing.

Comment: This the first time that I understand the use of Blueprints. I just implemented it (was surprised how easy it was) and it works like a charm. Thanks a million for the simple though very complete answer!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters. Can you please explain "Use per-view decorators rather than before_request.". Thanks

Comment: @Shafaq: use a decorator on each view that should have different behaviour. Write a decorator and apply that to each view with `@decorator`.